# Licensing Attribution on basic questions

Tags: support, legal, licensing

I know that the license for SO is [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

However, when one starting learning a language and find basic questions here, would it still be necessary the attribution?

In a very simple question such as [Java - Convert integer to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-integer-to-string) the user finds the answer there (which is pretty much on the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html)).

Should he still link it and make the attributions still?

```java
/**
The code below is from StackOverflow 
@Author: Rob Hruska (https://stackoverflow.com/users/29995/rob-hruska)
@Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java/5585800#5585800 
**/
int myint = Integer.parseInt(myString);
```

I do understand and agree that everything that someone does solve your problem and you use, that person deserves the credits, but it seems *silly* IMHO for such basic questions.

Comment: The only exception would be if it falls under fair use. *Silly* doesn't mean much legally.

Answer (score 8):

*Standard disclaimer: I am not a lawyer. Please see a lawyer if you want expert legal advice.*

This technically would come under the fair use provision. As [Jeff Atwood said in a similar pos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25957/237685)t:

> The cc-wiki license seems pretty clear to me on this point: free to remix and reuse, as long as you attribute and use a similar license.
>
> That said, a snippet of code falls under excerpt category and thus should be free to use under fair use. Heck, we don't even support giant masses of code being posted, so to me, by definition, everything would be an excerpt.

The only point where you might want to double check is if you're contributing to an open source project that has a different license. In whichcase, you might want to consult a lawyer.

So, while you *could* put this in your code, you shouldn't have to. If you want to though, you can.