# Does licensing permit using code found in answers on SO at work?

Tags: discussion, answers, legal, user-experience, licensing

I understand source code contained in answers on Stack Overflow are licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

If I'm getting paid to develop an application that is probably going to be closed source, does this mean I can't use any code I find on Stack Overflow (since it won't be licensed under CC)? Does it matter if I incorporate it into a much larger project and make changes to it?

If licensing doesn't permit the re-use of code in projects that are closed source, what is the expectation? To learn from the code posted in an answer well enough to be able to recreate the idea without having to look back at the posted code (since to my understanding the under lying idea can't be copyrighted)?

Comment: Realistically, if this were a problem, half the world's developers would be having legal issues.

Comment: It is not a restrictive license that stops you from using it.  The only point of it is to get you to properly attribute the author and the source of the code when you republish it for others to see.  You don't publish anything in a closed-source project.  Other than what the devs and maintainers that work on it can see.  Whom might well be helped if you *do* include the URL of the SO post in a comment  For background and for any future updates that might be useful in your project maintenance.  Just a good practice, it is up to you.

Comment: @HansPassant The __SA__ variant is viral, unfortunately. Any adaptation of the code needs to be shared using a compatible license. Afaik OP is technically right, you can't use the code found here in projects that are licensed using a CC BY SA incompatible license.

Comment: Wouldn't then any `If` `Then` `Else` clause be protected, and thus be an issue in your code? If you use parts of it you might as well say that you came up with it yourself. No-one that can verify that, unless you blatantly copy paste larger pieces of code. Also see for example this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267022/licensing-attribution-on-basic-questions?rq=1

Comment: @Luuklag You can't just license anything. It needs to be a _distinct work_ as far as I know (not a license lawyer), but really small and simple things can't be licensed because they aren't a distinct work. More complex code, however, is licensed.

Comment: That is not accurate, the license does not demand that you *must* republish adaptations.  Only if you *choose* to republish does it demand attribution.  Anybody can figure out whether they'll choose to.  Given the number of contributors compared to the number of askers and googlers (about 1 in 3 thousand) that is a very rare occurrence indeed :)

Comment: @Luuklag there's a threshold that has to be met for something to be copyrightable, it has to be non-trivial.

Comment: @HansPassant As far as I know, it does. Quote from CreativeCommons: _ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you __must distribute__ your contributions under the same license as the original._ (emphasis mine)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That's ambiguous language, but I don't believe it's saying that one is obligated to distribute the end work; only that if they choose to distribute it, then it must be under that license. I think it's less ambiguous if you consult [the legalese](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/legalcode): 4.a.+b. - _You **may** distribute..._ ;  4.c. - _**If** you distribute...You must keep intact all copyright notices..._ (emphasis mine).

Comment: @MikeM. Good point, I believe you're right, and the definiton of _distribute_ fortunately is pretty narrow: _"Distribute" means to make available to the public the original and copies of the Work or Adaptation, as appropriate, through sale or other transfer of ownership._ So I guess internal company applications are OK

Comment: Relevant information, although it doesn't actually bring any more clarity: [The MIT license: clarity on using code on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080)

Comment: @rocketsocks If you had to look it up and copy the code from SO, then you've implicitly conceded that *to you* it's non-trivial. If it was trivial, you wouldn't be looking it up and copying it for your own use.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the code is eligible for copyright protection, and assuming that the author had the right to license it under CC BY-SA 3.0 (so it would be [case {3}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271559/193139)):

You have to license your application under CC BY-SA 3.0, too, ***if*** you distribute the application.

(It doesn’t matter whether or not you make changes to the code. It doesn’t matter that the application is much larger.)

Examples that count as distribution:

- You offer the application for download, on CDs, etc. (no matter if as binary or source code, no matter if gratis or for sale).
- You offer hardware that comes pre-installed with the application.
- You install the application on computers of the company’s customers.

Examples that don’t count as distribution:

- You use the application only internally in the company.
- You install the application on your company’s public server, but users never get the binary nor the source code when interacting with the application on the server (e.g., it’s not client-side JavaScript).

#### What to do when you can’t (or don’t want to) license it accordingly?

> To learn from the code posted in an answer well enough to be able to recreate the idea without having to look back at the posted code (since to my understanding the under lying idea can't be copyrighted)?

Yes, that would be possible. Copyrighted/licensed is the specific expression, not the idea. See also: [clean room design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design).

Alternatives:

- Ask the author for permission to use the code under different terms (e.g., under a different license). Some authors might even give everyone such a permission in their user profile. See also: [multi-licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing).
- Structure your application in such a way that you have a CC-BY-SA-licensed part and a separate proprietary part. Whether this is allowed depends on how these parts "communicate" (however, as CC BY-SA was not intended for software, this is not clearly defined).

Comment: Given it's argued that snippets of code on SO are "works", then it could reasonably be argued that an entire program/software project would be considered a "Collection" of works, as defined in [CC-BY SA 3.0 § 1b](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode). "Collections" are explicitly exempt (CC-BY SA 3.0 § 4b) from having to apply an "Applicable License" to the entirety, only requiring the copied work to remain under such a license. As you mention, the CC licenses are not designed with software in mind. There is quite a bit of grey area that would need to be litigated.

Comment: If you use code from Stackoverflow in a closed sourced project for work, and your work decides to distribute the end result (not the code) to the public by download, would that be infringing?

Comment: @rocketsocks: Yes. They have to license it under CC BY-SA 3.0 (or under a compatible license).

Comment: @rocketsocks based on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1718 you don't have to distribute the source code. So you can distribute the end result under the same license without infringing.

Comment: @Oleg: Correct. Open Source SE also has a dedicated question about this: [Does the CC-BY-SA License require that source code of derivative works be shared?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1849/138)